# NetTcpBinding and Windows 7 firewall

Tags: .net, wcf, windows-7, net.tcp, windows-firewall

I have an wcf winforms self-hosted app using nettcpbinding.(net.tcp://aaa.homeip.net:9388)
The problem is windows 7 firewall, I added the exception on the inbound and outbound list (port 9388) but still doesnt work(even if the client is in the same machine)...I also tried to add Distributed Transaction Coordinator on the program list like [this hint](http://www.packtpub.com/article/how-configure-msdtc-firewall-distributed-wcf-service) but no success...
Everything works fine when firewall is disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add/enable Windows Communication Foundation Net.TCP Listener Adapter (TCP-In) in Inbound Rules in Windows Firewall with Advanced Security