# .Net WCF Web Service Can't Connect from Client to Remote server

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, nettcpbinding

I have a client that connects to a WCF web server using NetTCPBinding.  I have having issues connecting to the WCF remotely from certain machines.

I can run this client from my other computer to the remote web service however I have a new machine and I cannot connect to the WCF service while running the same client from this machine and I can't figure out why since I have not changed anything in the clients on both machines, they are exactly the same.

I get the error

***"The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue."***

So my question is,

Is there anything on a system level that could be blocking my client from making the connection to the service?

Thanks

Comment: So many questions. Show us your `web.config`. Are you using IIS Express or IIS proper? Is `net.tcp` set up as a valid binding in IIS? Is WCF installed via the Windows Programs and Features?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354439/nettcpbinding-and-windows-7-firewall ?

Comment: A firewall can block your access. Do you use only `netTcpBinding`? If you have a `basicHttpBinding` you can try to access through a browser. To check out if you can reach the service using `netTcpBinding`, you can also try to connect to server using telnet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310153/how-to-ping-or-check-status-of-wcf-service-using-net-tcp-endpoint-from-remote-se

Comment: Have you got a limit on the number of connections available at a single time

Comment: @stuartd I just took a look in IIS Manager on the new machine, it uses IIS 8.5 and I tried to add nettcp to the bindings but I can't find nettcp.  Is it not supported after certain versions of IIS?

Comment: Have you enabled WCF non-HTTP activation in Windows Programs and Features? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731053%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396